# Body text special characters are escaped

Tags: entities, 9

I have this code which I am using to get the body text from a node rewrite it with a regular expression and replace it, (I am replacing all you tube video links with embed codes)

```
function hook_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  switch ($entity->bundle()) {
    case 'article':

    $node_body = $entity->get('body')->value;

    Drupal::logger('origin-body')->notice($node_body);


    $node_body_replaced = preg_replace('/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/', '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $node_body);

      Drupal::logger('replaced-body')->notice($node_body_replaced);
      $body_encoded = htmlspecialchars($node_body_replaced, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      //$entity->body = $node_body_replaced;
      $entity->set( 'body',$body_encoded  ); // This appears to be where special characters are getting escaped
      
     break;
  }
}
```

Both my logger messages show normal text output in the drupal log so I guess it happens somwhere when the node gets saved or $entity->set().  I have tried running through htmlspecialchars() and it does nothing.

For example, I am migrating content from WordPress and after running through this function my normal HTML becomes

> <p>lorem ipsum dolar lorem ipsum dolar lorem ipsum dolar lorem
> ipsum dolar lorem ipsum dolar lorem ipsum dolar .</p> <!--
> /wp:paragraph -->

I am using Drupal 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by *my normal HTML becomes* you mean the escaped HTML is rendering on the front end, you're probably just resetting the format for the body field with this line

```
$entity->set('body', $body_encoded);
```

You can target the value directly instead like this (and you shouldn't need to encode/decode anything):

```
$entity->body->value = preg_replace('/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/', '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $node_body);
```

If that isn't working you can try setting the format too:

```
// Possibly change 'full_html' to whatever's appropriate for your site.
$entity->body->format = 'full_html';
```